# Sticky topshelf service that refuses to terminate

Tags: windows-services, topshelf

I have a project that includes a topshelf service and the deployment script uninstalls and reinstalls the newer version on the server.

This worked fine for a long time until last week when it started misbehaving for unknown reasons.

What happens now is the command:

```
D:/Deploy/current/net40/MyService.exe uninstall
```

Prints out these results:

```
The uninstall is beginning.
2017-03-06T11:21:07 [1] INFO  Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.HostInstaller - Uninstalling MyService service
Removing EventLog source MyService.
Service MyService is being removed from the system...
Service MyService was successfully removed from the system.
Attempt to stop service Halcyon.
The uninstall has completed.
```

But MyService.exe is still running in TaskManager.

As a result

This command:

```
D:/Deploy/current/net40/MyService.exe install --manual
```

gives this (expected) error:

```
ERROR Topshelf.Hosts.InstallHost - The MyService service is already installed.
```

I tried updating Topshelf to the latest version.
Uninstalling and killing the service manually on the deployment server doesn't work either because of another bizarre error.

```
Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
2017-03-06T11:40:08 [1] INFO  Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.HostInstaller - Installing MyService service
Installing service MyService...
Service MyService has been successfully installed.

The Install phase completed successfully, and the Commit phase is beginning.

The Commit phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.
INFO  MyService.Program - Exiting Main() - exitCode:Ok
INFO  Dozo::Applications::Topshelf - Starting MyService
INFO  Dozo::Applications::Topshelf - Changing MyService to start automatically
INFO  Dozo::Dozo - sc config "MyService" start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS
INFO Dozo::Applications::Topshelf - Starting MyService
INFO  Dozo::Dozo - net start "MyService"
The MyService service is starting........
The MyService service could not be started.
```

I just can't figure out why this is happening.
I tried adding more error logging but nothing has come up.

Anyone had this before? Any ideas how to get this "Sticky" service to stop running even after an uninstall?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi have you tried to remove the service with windows commands?

Open a Command Prompt and enter

```
sc delete <service-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late but I hope that someone else might find it useful.

When having issues like this you should look into `Stop` method in your Topshelf configuration. Make sure that everything is disposed in it. Like various connections are closed and file handles are disposed. This kind of stuff can make your service "Sticky".